# Can`t run Python code computing Fourier Transform on .tiff image? How to manage memory?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

My Python code, designed for computation of Fourier Transform can`t complete the task.

```
  def fouriertransform(result):     #function for FTM computation
    for filename in glob.iglob('*.tif'):
     imgfourier = scipy.misc.imread(filename, flatten = True)
     image = np.array([imgfourier])#make an array as np
     arr = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(image)))**2
      with open('сomput.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
       for elem in arr.flat[:50]:
       writer = csv.writer(csvfile, .....)
       writer.writerow([('{}\t'.format(elem))])
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack.py", line 524, in _raw_fftnd
  a = function(a, n=s[ii], axis=axes[ii])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack.py", line 164, in fft
  return _raw_fft(a, n, axis, fftpack.cffti, fftpack.cfftf, _fft_cache)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack.py", line 75, in _raw_fft
  r = work_function(a, wsave)
```

MemoryError

Image is large 90 MB, how to solve the problem if it works on 1-5 MB images somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- The `scipy.fftpack` functions allow you the option of overwriting your input array (`overwrite_x=True`), which may buy you some memory savings.
- You could also try [`anfft`](https://code.google.com/p/anfft/) (or the newer [pyFFTW](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/)), which is just a Python wrapper around the FFTW C libraries. It's definitely much faster than the numpy and scipy FFT functions, and at least in my hands it seems to also be a bit more memory-efficient.
- Could you maybe cast your array to a lower bit depth (float64->float32, uint16->uint8)?
- You could always downsample your image first (e.g. using `scipy.ndimage.zoom`). Reducing the spatial resolution of the image will of course reduce the spectral resolution of the FFT, but it might not matter that much to you depending on what exactly you want to do with it.
- Buy some more RAM?